# React js Post Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display all post function on my home page but got an untype error of length.
Function in my Post component in Post .js file

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
//Again import {Link} from react Router Dom. Post component will recieve the post as a props.

```
const Post = ({ post }) => {
    return (
        <article className="post">
        
            <Link to={`/post/${post.id}`}>
                <h2>{post.title}</h2>
                <p className="postDate">{post.datetime}</p>
            </Link>
            <p className="postBody">{
                (post.body).length <= 25
                    ? post.body
                    : `${(post.body).slice(0, 25)}...`
            }</p>
        </article>
    )
}

export default Post
```

All css files are also correct. I am attaching the screen Hot of the error amy image of my code snippet
[image: Code Snippet]
[image: Error Page]

App.js File Here all I am using all posts from hard code in the form of array.

```
import Header from './Header';
import Nav from './Nav';
import Footer from './Footer';
import Home from './Home';
import NewPost from './NewPost';
import PostPage from './PostPage';
import About from './About';
import Missing from './Missing';
import { Route, Switch, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { format } from 'date-fns';

function App() {
  
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "My First Post", 
      datetime: "July 01, 2021 11:17:36 AM",
      body: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis consequatur expedita, assumenda similique non optio! Modi nesciunt excepturi corrupti atque blanditiis quo nobis, non optio quae possimus illum exercitationem ipsa!"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "My 2nd Post",
      datetime: "July 01, 2021 11:17:36 AM",
      body: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis consequatur expedita, assumenda similique non optio! Modi nesciunt excepturi corrupti atque blanditiis quo nobis, non optio quae possimus illum exercitationem ipsa!"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "My 3rd Post",
      datetime: "July 01, 2021 11:17:36 AM",
      body: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis consequatur expedita, assumenda similique non optio! Modi nesciunt excepturi corrupti atque blanditiis quo nobis, non optio quae possimus illum exercitationem ipsa!"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      title: "My Fourth Post",
      datetime: "July 01, 2021 11:17:36 AM",
      body: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis consequatur expedite, assumenda similique non optio! Modi nesciunt excepturi corrupti atque blanditiis quo nobis, non optio quae possimus illum exercitationem ipsa!"
    }
  ])

  //Here we want search results therefore we want to use empty strings.
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  
    
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header title="React JS Blog" />
      <Nav search={search} setSearch={setSearch} />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
        {/**passing post in Home component */}
          <Home  posts = {posts}/>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/post">
          <NewPost
            
          />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/post/:id">
          <PostPage />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="*" component={Missing} />
      </Switch>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: We can't tell you why `post.body` is `undefined`. It's a prop, and you haven't shown the code that is passing the  object with an `undefined` value for the `body` property into it.

Comment: I have pasted my App.js file where all posts are saved in an array object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access inner objects without mapping the array. You should map them like this

```
const Post = ({ post }) => {
    return (
             <>
             {post?.map((postObject) => (
               <article className="post">
                 <Link to={`/post/${postObject.id}`}>
                  <h2>{postObject.title}</h2>
                  <p className="postDate">{postObject.datetime}</p>
                  </Link>
                  <p className="postBody">{
                  postObject.body.length <= 25
                  ? postObject.body
                  : `${(postObject.body).slice(0, 25)}...`
                  }</p>
               </article>
               ))}
            </>
      )
}

export default Post
```

Comment: Thank you Evren, Can you guide me please how did you debug this because apparently there in no syntax error and not any specific answer against this error code available on internet.